# Creating and using a global binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

How do I create a global binding in knockout?

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-6" data-bind="visible: IsPayingUser">
    <!-- the server will not send any data for freemium, 
         so hide the element unless it's a paying customer -->
</div>
```

That is, I do not want to create `IsPayingUser` as a property in every view model, but define it one time only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can instruct Knockout to explicitly 'escape' the View-Model scope by using the `window` keyword:

```
<div class="col-lg-6" data-bind="visible: window.UserData.IsPayingUser">
```

And in your JavaScript:

```
window.UserData = { IsPayingUser = ko.observable(false) };
```

It's worth noting though that the 'Knockout way' to do it is to use nested View-Models and try to avoid pollution of the global scope.

Comment: +1, good answer. To add to this, for the "nested view model case", there's also a way to find the "global" *knockout* scope, i.e. the `$root`. See: [binding context](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html).